# Draw a circle every second in a video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have some points to be plotted in a video per second for object tracking.

I can read the video easily using VideoCapture from opencv. But when I draw some circles on the video frame, the drawing is faster as compared to the video frames.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
radius = [None]*10
radius = (1,2)
radius.append((2,3))
radius.append((3,4))
radius.append((4,5))
radius.append((5,6))
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  for i in range(len(radius)):
    cv2.circle(frame, radius[i], 5, (0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.imshow('test', frame)  # draw
each_second += 1
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I draw a 'n' number of circle each frame in this case. But I want to draw them each second how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `waitKey` value to `1000` to wait for a second.

Comment: I figured it out i simply added these lines:
 time_passed = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
 if time_passed % 1000 ==0:
  print(time_passed)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible but just a thought.

If you know the FPS for the video can you just make a counter which can tell if a second has passed by how many frames have gone by?

For example if you have a 60 FPS video you can count for 60 frames to know a second has gone by.

Comment: thank you yes, this is possible it worked for me perfectly :) (check the question for solution) sorry I do not know how to add solution separately

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
radius = [None]*10
radius = (1,2)
radius.append((2,3))
radius.append((3,4))
radius.append((4,5))
radius.append((5,6))
while(cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()
time_passed = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
if time_passed % 1000 ==0:
  print(time_passed)
  # draw circles
  for i in range(len(radius)):
    cv2.circle(frame, radius[i], 5, (0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.imshow('test', frame)  # draw

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```